# generate non normal data for simulations

Tags: r, classification, regression

To perform some test (regression and classification) I need to create synthetic datasets that have a NON NORMAL distribution. 
I would like to have a function that takes some parameters from a given dataframe and transform the original dataframe to generate a new NON NORMAL dataframe. 
This is the code I have tried until now, but it seems not to work properly, I do not know where I am missing up.

```
data (rock) 
gendf2 <- function(df, vi,vf,var.names=NULL){
  if (ncol < 2) stop("ncol must be greater than 1")
  nc <- ncol(df)
  nr <- nrow (df)
    valin <- c(sample(0:vi, nc, replace=TRUE))
      valfin <- c(sample(vi:vf, nc, replace=FALSE))
      for (i in 1:length(valin)){
        for (j in 1:length(valfin)){
    DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(replicate(n = nc, runif(n=nr, min = valin[i], max = valfin[j]))))

  if (!is.null(var.names)) colnames(DF) <- var.names
  return(DF)
      }
}
}
```

What I would like to have is a function that generates a non normal dataframe. I have seen that there is the package (nor1mix)for Marron-Wand distribution,  but the examples are not helping me, I am just getting more confused. Please any minimal example or guide to get a function like this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: R functions only return 1 value. Having return(DF) within the loop doesn't make sense as the first time the code reaches that line, DF will be returned and the function will stop.

Comment: Also if(ncol < 2) should be if(ncol(df) < 2)

Comment: There are many types of non-normal data. Do you want data to follow any kind of distribution such as gamma, beta, binomial, etc., etc., etc.?

Comment: No, I am not interested on specific kind of distribution. i am just intereste in getting an user-friendly function to construct a non normalized dataframe

Comment: @timcdlucas, Ok, i see the error

Comment: @timcdlucas, I have moved `return (DF)`outside the loop as suggested but i am still having problems, do not know what I am doing wrong, any idea?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want. What are vi and vf?

Comment: I was attempting at using a given dataframe with normal distribution and transform it to non-normal distribution. Thus, vi and vf will be taken from the min and max values from the given dataframe. But i am not sure if this is a good idea. probably start constructing a dataframe from a non-normal distribution?